# Finding the date a file was moved into a folder

Tags: file, date, powershell

Ok, here is the scenario. I have a folder that people can use to share data around. Quick and easy, no USB needed. However they tend to leave the data in there and it is filling up the HDD. I want to delete everything over 30 days old. I was going to do this with powershell -

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)
$path = "C:\temp"

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } | Remove-Item -Force -whatif

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -and (Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer }) -eq $null } | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse -whatif
```

I left the -whatif there because that makes it easier to test.

So I tested it, and it works fine, but during the testing I ran into a small problem. Moved files retain their **original** creation date. Why is this important? Because a user might move something into the folder 5 minutes before the script runs, and it will get deleted if the **creation date** is older than 30 days. Copying a file is no problem, it gets a new creation date when copied. Its only the moved files.

So question, how do I find the date the file was moved into the folder so that it isn't accidentally deleted?

Comment: Have you tried checking if [`LastWriteTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.lastwritetime(v=vs.110).aspx) values would be more up to date?

Comment: I tried the LastWriteTime but it also doesn't change when the file is moved. This might only happen 2% of the time but our users can be very fickle :)

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, there's a hidden fourth modification time in windows: ChangeTime.  As far as I understand it, it's stored in a separate place, and isn't returned by the normal APIs - it's part of the Master File Table, I think.  (Perhaps it depends on your file system type?)  Whether that description is accurate or not, consider the following:

```
C:\Users\erhannis\Downloads\nsx220en>stat nsx-2.2.0
  File: nsx-2.2.0
  Size: 0               Blocks: 4          IO Block: 65536  directory
Device: c6194f59h/3323547481d   Inode: 7318349397564576  Links: 1
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (1056947/   erhannis)   Gid: (1049089/ UNKNOWN)
Access: 2016-03-24 14:41:17.880026600 -0400
Modify: 2016-03-24 14:41:17.880026600 -0400
Change: 2020-12-01 17:03:41.697541400 -0500
 Birth: 2016-03-24 14:35:09.540397700 -0400
```

(See links for relevant programs.)

The time listed next to `Change:` is the time I moved the folder from one place to another.  When I move a file, the `Change` date is updated.  Note: I tried moving a folder full of files, and it appears only the root object's `ChangeTime` is updated.  So like, for your purposes, you would consider the last `ChangeTime` of a given file to be the newest of the `ChangeTime` of the file and any parent directory.  (Or, just stop recursing into directories when you hit a change time too new; depends on how you're doing it.)

Perhaps more relevantly, the Linux `find` command has a parameter `-cmin` that lets you filter by "metadata more recently changed than X".  So, for instance, `find -cmin -5` recursively finds all items whose metadata (e.g., when it was last moved) has changed less than five minutes ago.  (`find -cmin 5` would find files changed MORE than 5 minutes ago.)  (On windows, I rename the `find` command to something else so it doesn't conflict with the default windows `find` command.)

Windows ports of both `stat` and `find` are available incidentally as part of a Git installation:
https://git-scm.com/download/win

There's also this Powershell script I found - haven't tried it, but it purports to get the `ChangeTime` of a file.
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-MFT-Timestamp-of-a-file-9227f399

Answer (score 0):

This topic may have already been covered here: [Finding Modified Date of a file/folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19774097/powershell-script-for-finding-modified-date-of-a-file-folder)

Is this more or less what you are looking for or are you looking specifically for the **creation** date? I would imagine that some of the files may have been created on 1/1/2016, but the user might be modifying it every so often so it could be last modified on 2/15/2016. I'm sure you wouldn't want to remove that otherwise you would have one very angry end user.

Comment: Unfortunately the creation date doesn't change when the file is moved. So it could be moved over 5 minutes before the script is run, leaving the user no time to modify it, and the script will delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so short answer is it can't be done. In the end I have had to copy the folder to an archive folder on another server as a backup, and then delete everything in the folder. The backup then gets deleted 10 days later.

But some things I found out along the way.

1. Using Robocopy to move the files also deletes the root folder. This might be ok for some cases, but the root folder has permissions on it that aren't created with a simple "make directory" command
2. Using Move-Item in powershell doesn't like to work between servers
3. Powershell is limited by the path and file length limitations that windows has

What I ended up doing was copying all the files to an archive first

```
robocopy $SourceFolder $DestinationFolder /e
```

Then I wanted to delete all the files. Which Remove-Item can't do if the path is longer than 248 characters because of the file and path length limitations. Again, robocopy to the rescue. I have a blank folder. Nothing in it. And to delete all the items in the other folder, regardless of path and file length, I mirror the blank folder.

```
robocopy /mir $EmptyFolder $SourceFolder
```

I already had a powershell script so I stuck these commands in there. But as it isn't a powershell command, then you could replace the variables with the actual folders and put the commands straight into a .bat file.

From here I just put in a scheduled task to run the script once a month to keep the folder free of built up clutter.

I hope this helps anyone else who is trying to do something similar.