# Using Test-Path -NewerThan to check date of files

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have the following method to verify the presence of a file in a remote folder where I need to check the date of the file must be the current date.

If I execute the below statement it seems to work

```
$Exs = Test-Path  '\\srvcld\Homeware\Applications\Processed\Soc*' -NewerThan (Get-Date -UFormat "%d/%m/%Y")
```

But when it run in the entiere script it returns the following error:

> Test-Path : Cannot bind parameter 'NewerThan'. Cannot convert value "02/23/2018" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Do you know another method that could be used to verify the existence of the files from the current date?

Comment: You can refer the same topic discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19774097/finding-modified-date-of-a-file-folder

Comment: Your original code works fine for me with PSv5. `[datetime]::Today` will return a midnight DateTime which should do what you want, but I can't test with v4... `-NewerThan ([datetime]::Today)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might helps you

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "<path>" | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -ge (Get-Date).Date}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't format the date. This converts it to a `[String]`, and relies on your culture when converting this back to `[DateTime]`.

Instead, keep is as a `[DateTime]` object and pass this to `Test-Path`. [That's the type it's expecting anyway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path?view=powershell-6#optional-parameters):

```
$Exs = Test-Path  '\\srvcld\Homeware\Applications\Processed\Soc*' -NewerThan (Get-Date).Date
```

To add to [Dharini's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48989051/5039142), this gives the current date but not time. Run the below if you'd like to see the types.

---

```
$date1 = Get-Date -UFormat "%d/%m/%Y"
$date2 = (Get-Date).Date

$date1.GetType()     # returns String
$date2.GetType()     # returns DateTime
```