# SQL Server Agent job that will run a cmd command to check a file creation date and then sends an email with that information

Tags: sql-server, batch-file

I need to create a job (either windows batch or SQL Server Agent job) that will run a cmd command that checks a file creation date and then sends an email with that information. Is there a way to create a send email task to do that?
The cmd command would be something like: 
dir /T:W "\networkfolder\" | findstr filename.csv
And it would return the file creation date information. I want to have an email sent out with that information.
Thanks

Comment: SSIS package would be your best bet.  Or you could write a C# app and execute the .exe file from the job but the job agent would need access to the path you are storing the .exe file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SQL Server**

You can use [xp_cmdshell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to run what ever command you want, and output the results.

Then, you'd use [sp_send_dbmail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to send the email based on what ever logic you want.

**PowerShell**

This seems to be the more logical choice, since SQL Server isn't needed at all. You can do something similar in a batch file.

Run what ever command you want in an `IF()` statement to [figure out the date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19774097/finding-modified-date-of-a-file-folder), and then send an email based off the result.

`IF(...){
        Send-MailMessage -To "ME <me@domain.com>" -From "Server <server@domain.com>" -Subject "Some condition was met" -Body "some relevant info"
}`