# latest .bak file in windows folder using sql script

Tags: t-sql

I need help to write the sql script to find the latest backup file from the windows folder to restore the database. filename is like:-

```
dbnm_2019_4_5_11_30_613.bak
dbnm_2019_4_18_11_32_234.bak
dbnm_2019_4_11_11_37_34.bak
```

... name is made up using dbnm_year_month_date_hr_min_sec format.

used below script:-

```
CREATE TABLE #File
     ( FileName    SYSNAME,
        Depth       TINYINT,
        IsFile      TINYINT
        );
 INSERT INTO #File
        (FileName, Depth, IsFile)
 EXEC xp_DirTree '[file location]',1,1;
```

is there anyway that I can insert date filed from the network folder to show when the backup file created and do the order by on that field to find the latest file.

when I am using top 1 in select statement, it is showing me `2019_4_5_11_30_613.bak` as latest file which is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway that I can insert date filed from the network folder
>   to show when the backup file created and do the order by on that field
>   to find the latest file.

SQL Server recovery databases from files only from computer unitys (c: d: ).

To get the backup sets I use this statment:

```
SELECT
    database_name as DataBaseName,
    physical_device_name as PhysicalDeviceName,
    backup_start_date as BackupStartDate,
    backup_finish_date as BackupFinishDate,
    cast(backup_size/1024.0 as decimal(19,2)) AS BackupSizeKB,
    cast(backup_size/1024.0/1024.0 as decimal(19,2)) AS BackupSizeMB,
    cast(backup_size/1024.0/1024/1024.0 as decimal(19,2))  AS BackupSizeGB
FROM msdb.dbo.backupset b
JOIN msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily m ON b.media_set_id = m.media_set_id
where cast(b.backup_finish_date as date)= (cast(getdate() -1 as date))

ORDER BY backup_finish_date
```

Pay attention to the clauses: WHERE and ORDER BY.

There is another way to get from windows folders the last file using powershell.
Take a look into Keith Hill answer here: [Finding modified date of a file/folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19774097/finding-modified-date-of-a-file-folder)